# Transforming int to char with input (edited)

Tags: java

My program should transform a letter to the letter which is 2 letter away from it. Like a to c, b to d.
And i can only use first 10 letters in english alphabet. ('i' will go to 'a' and 'j' will go to 'b' cuz i can only use 10 letters.

```
 import java.util.Scanner;
    public class part6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a 4 letter word only uses the first 10 letter on english alphabet(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):  ");

    Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1 = keyboard.next();
    String s2 = "z1";
    s2=s1.toLowerCase();

if (s1.length() !=4)
System.out.println("please enter a word with 4 letters");

char c1= s2.charAt(0);
char c2= s2.charAt(1);
char c3= s2.charAt(2);
char c4= s2.charAt(3);

int i1 =(int) c1;
int i2= (int) c2;
int i3= (int) c3;
int i4= (int) c4;

if(i1>96 && i1<107) // a = 97 , j = 106
System.out.println(s2);
else if (i2>96 && i2<107)
System.out.println(s2);
else if (i3>96 && i3<107)
System.out.println(s2);
else if (i4>96 && i4<107)
System.out.println(s2);
else 
System.out.println("wrong character using!");
}
}
```

So the new problem is the uhm even if i enter abcy or aaaq , i get abcy and aaaq.
the int does not work. What should i do ?

Comment: How about actually transforming the string? Now you read a string, put it into lowercase and print it out.

Comment: How exactly can i do that ? index the characters and do the thing ?

Comment: Go through the string character at a time, transform the character based on the rules and add to a new string

Comment: But i dont know what input will be ? So i cant do that

Answer (score 0):

**Step 1 :**

Test if the input is between 'a' and 'j' for each character

**Step 2 :**

Use a switch with three cases : 'i', 'j' & default that will output the wanted value

**Step 3 :**

Concatenate the results in a String object.

Here is the code solution :

```
public static void main(String arg[]){
    String input = "abcdefghij";
    String output = "";
    if (checkValidity(input)){
        for (int i = 0 ; i < input.length() ; i++){
            output += encrypt(input.charAt(i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println(output);
}

public static boolean checkValidity(String str){
    for (char c : str.toCharArray()){
        if (c < 'a' || c > 'j'){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

public static char encrypt (char c){
    switch (c){
    case 'i' : return (char) (c-8);
    case 'j' : return (char) (c-8); 
    default : return  (char) (c+2);
    }
}
```

Comment: It would not help you imo. I gave you the algorithm... Make good use of it

Comment: I coldnt do anything :/ can you help me?

Comment: Thank you but i cant use loops

Answer (score 0):

I a little cleaned up your code. Maybe something like this works like you want?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Part6 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("Please enter a 4 letter word only uses the first 10 letter on english alphabet(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j):  ");

        Scanner keyboard=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input = keyboard.next();

        if (input.length() !=4) {
            System.out.println("please enter a word with 4 letters");
            return;
        }

        transformAndPrint(input.charAt(0));
        transformAndPrint(input.charAt(1));
        transformAndPrint(input.charAt(2));
        transformAndPrint(input.charAt(3));
    }

    private static void transformAndPrint(char inputChar) {
        if(inputChar>96 && inputChar<107) {
            int newChar = inputChar - 96;
            newChar = (newChar + 2) % 10;
            newChar = newChar + 96;
            System.out.print((char) newChar);
        } else {
            System.out.print(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i am not supposed to use loops. I can only use strings , if-else and switch. And i cant use private static.

Comment: I don't use loop. if you can't use private method (it sound very strange) you can just write this code four time.

Comment: @JJJ where is the mistake?

Comment: its says : cannot find sybol : if(input.lenght() !=4) { .      and arrow points the '.'

Comment: @JJJ If you compile and run my code, it impossible to get that error.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static char transform(char s){
        int base = s - 'a';
        int increment = base + 2;
        int circularShiftIncrement = increment % 10;
        int transformToCharValue = circularShiftIncrement + 'a';

        return (char)transformToCharValue;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        while(scanner.hasNext()){
            String s = scanner.next();
            char c = s.charAt(0);
            char transformedString = transform(c);
            System.out.println(transformedString);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much but i am not supposed to use loops. I can only use strings , if-else and switch.